# Count distinct from a bootstrapped sample

Tags: estimation, sampling, bootstrap

I have a dataset of `N` items, with attribute `V` which can be repetitive, for example:

```
City | Country
--------------
NYC  | USA
LA   | USA
LON  | UK
MAN  | UK
AMS  | NL
```

After bootstrapping the dataset into `M` groups on size `N` with replacement, I want to estimate the `COUNT(DISTINCT V)` in each of the group. However since the bootstrapping is with replacement, some of the element might repeat, and the cardinality of V will be smaller then the original.

For example I could get in one of the groups:

```
City | Country
--------------
NYC  | USA
LA   | USA
LON  | UK
LON  | UK
NYC  | USA
```

and then the estimation of `COUNT(DISTINCT Country)` would be 2 instead of 3.

Is there a way to estimate the original value through the values from bootstrapping?